# SharePoint Certification Suggestions

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, office-365

I am a SharePoint developer, having 5+ years of experience in SharePoint development. Currently working in O365, Planning to do a SharePoint Certification now, I am a little bit confused about which SharePoint certification should I take and where to start and learn, since this is my first certification. Any suggestion would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there are no such Microsoft certifications available for SharePoint **development**.

But there are multiple certifications available related to Microsoft Office 365 which are mostly inclined to administration side like configuring and managing services.

[Microsoft 365 certification exams](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/learning/microsoft-365-exams.aspx).

Below are some of the SharePoint certifications currently available:

1. [Microsoft SharePoint 2013](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/learning/exam-77-419.aspx).
2. [Managing Microsoft SharePoint Server 2016](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/learning/exam-70-339.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Ganesh for your info!

Comment: Welcome. Please upvote ( ^ ) and [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

In office 365, we can use SharePoint online. SharePoint online as a service exists in office 365.

Firstly, you should choose the office 365 plan option which includes the SharePoint online services according to the article below.

[Office 365 Plan Options.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/office-365-platform-service-description/office-365-plan-options)

Then, you could choose different SharePoint online options according to the article below.

[Compare SharePoint Online options.](https://products.office.com/en-us/sharepoint/compare-sharepoint-plans)

And we can setup a development environment on office 365. For more detailed information, refer to the article below.

[Set up a development environment for SharePoint Add-ins on Office 365.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/set-up-a-development-environment-for-sharepoint-add-ins-on-office-365)

More reference:

[SharePoint Online Service Description.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/sharepoint-online-service-description/sharepoint-online-service-description)

Comment: The question is regarding SharePoint certifications. Your links are pointing to SharePoint subscription plans.